# How to use Postcard stamps to send a regular letter

Tags: office-supplies, stationery, packaging

Okay, so I screwed up. I needed stamps, the local post office I knew of is closed during my work hours, so I ordered some on Amazon. When they showed up, I realized that they were postcard stamps.

I could send them back, but that would be a hassle. Can I send a regular letter by putting two of them on the envelope? Is there any other way to use them? (I don't see sending postcards any time soon.)

P.S. I am not at all sure this is the right kind of question for this site. If you know of a SE site where it would fit better, feel free to send this there.

Comment: Honestly this doesn't sound like a question for lifehacks. I would recommend looking on the web page of the mail services that operate in the respective country where you are trying to send the letter from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stamps are stamps, at least in the United States. Right now, your post card stamps are worth 34 cents each, and a typical letter costs 49 cents to mail. So yes, you can put 2 postcard stamps on a regular letter to mail it.

Comment: You could also go into an open Post Office and buy 15 cent stamps, or a combination of 10 and 5 cent stamps.  These seem like odd denominations, but they're still sold as make-up stamps -- to make-up an amount for which you don't have an exact match.  They even still sell one cent stamps.